# SQLite returning wrong data

Tags: database, sqlite

I have 22 rows of data. But after running this query

```
select
  AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID,
  ABSTRACT_AFFILIATION.AFFILIATION_NUMBER,
  AUTHORS_AFFILIATE.ABSTRACTAUTHOR_ID  

from 
  ABSTRACT_AFFILIATION,
  AUTHORS_AFFILIATE,
  AUTHORS_ABSTRACT

where         ABSTRACT_AFFILIATION._id = AUTHORS_AFFILIATE.ABSTRACTAFFILIATION_ID
and AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTAUTHOR_ID = AUTHORS_AFFILIATE.ABSTRACTAUTHOR_ID

ORDER BY AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID ASC
```

and If you need the `.db` file here is my db [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ey1dl5habg4raf9/Test) . So, after running this query I get 36 rows of data.

So, my question is Why it returns 36 rows, even 22 rows data exist in the database.

Comment: Your test.db file is actually test.exe please change extension.

Comment: @davidstrachan nope, it was just `Test`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

The table you are joining have 22 rows each. And the `join` query you are running on them will have `22^3` rows out of which 36 rows end up meeting the conditions of your query.

Nothing wrong with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
select     AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID,
           ABSTRACT_AFFILIATION.AFFILIATION_NUMBER,
           AUTHORS_AFFILIATE.ABSTRACTAUTHOR_ID
   from AUTHORS_ABSTRACT
   left join ABSTRACT_AFFILIATION on AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTAUTHOR_ID = ABSTRACT_AFFILIATION._id
   left join AUTHORS_AFFILIATE on ABSTRACT_AFFILIATION._id=AUTHORS_AFFILIATE.ABSTRACTAFFILIATION_ID
   ORDER BY AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to  AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID = 4(id number). how would be like query ?

Comment: add where clause before order by: WHERE AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID = 4 ORDER BY AUTHORS_ABSTRACT.ABSTRACTSITEM_ID ASC

Comment: It gives only right information for 1 & 2. Would you please help me.